# How to make components/app wait for ajax call

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to find the best way to have my application and components rely on a single ajax call that I'm making. My app gets authenticated through a 3rd party and to really show any meaningful information to the user I have to use the info from their sign on and then call another service to get details about them. I've drawn from a couple of examples and so far have this

```
//auth.js
module.exports = {
  login(cb) {
    if (this.user) {
      if (cb) cb(true)
      this.onChange(true)
      return;
    }
    //if we don't have info about the user we call the other service here
    request((res) => {
      if (res) {
        this.user = res
        if (cb) cb(true)
        this.onChange(true)
      } else {
        if (cb) cb(false)
        this.onChange(false)
      }
    })
  },

  getUser() {
    return this.user
  },

  logout(cb) {
    delete this.user
    if (cb) cb()
    this.onChange(false)
  },

  loggedIn() {
    return !!this.user
  },

  onChange() {}
}
```

then in my components I'm doing this all over the place which just doesn't seem like a great pattern.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import auth from './auth'

export class ProductList extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      //subscribe to on change event from the auth class
      auth.onChange = this.updateAuth.bind(this)
      this.state = {results: []};
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    //call login. if already logged in this method just returns the current user
    auth.login();
  }

  getProducts() {
    if(this.state.loggedIn) {
      $.get(config.server.url + "/api/User/" + auth.getUser().Id + "/Products", function(result) {
        this.setState({
          results: result.data.products
        });
      }.bind(this));
    }
  }

  updateAuth(loggedIn) {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: loggedIn
    });
    this.getProducts()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProducts()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
            {this.state.results.map(function(result) {
               return <ProductItem key={result.Id} data={result}/>;
            })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  (<ProductList/>),
  document.getElementById('react-forms')
);
```

So I basically just hook up an event handler in every single react component I have and check the same properties all over the place and it just seems fragile. I guess I'm looking for a way to tell me 'App' that I'm waiting for something to happen first before my components are valid.

Comment: Its hard to tell what your component structure looks like, but have you considered making the ajax call in a top level component, then passing an `auth` prop to sub components, which will show data based on the value of that prop?

Comment: @Mark I added a bit more to my example. right now I've got a pretty naive setup since I'm not using anything like redux or react-router right now. Just trying to replace a couple components I have in a knockout application. I like your idea of making a top level component but I'm a bit new to React and don't quite know the best way to do that. I see the composite components and stuff like that but I'm not quite sure how to extend or wrap components. any examples would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow the structure outlined in the react tutorial (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#fetching-from-the-server).  The ajax call is made from the top-level component `CommentBox` using the jquery ajax function, and then passed down to other components `CommentList` and `CommentForm` via props.  The code below is taken directly from the tutorial.  The syntax is slightly different since you are using es6, but the concepts remain the same.

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
        <CommentForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```